# retrieve input values from creativebulma/bulma-tagsinput in React

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am using this as a standalone TagInput component, where whenever I want to use it, I will import it and use it like:

```js
<TagsInput
  attribute="tags"
  label="Tags"
  value={eventForm.tags}
  placeholder="Choose Tags"
  changed={handleChange}
/>
```

Unfortunately, `@creativebulma/bulma-tagsinput` doesn't detect `onChange`, as such, I can't retrieve the values that are within the TagInput. What am I missing here?

This code is taken and modified from original [codepen](https://codepen.io/CreativeBulma/pen/PoPJVQx) provided by creativebulma:

```js
import React from "react";
import BulmaTagsInput from "@creativebulma/bulma-tagsinput";

export default class TagsInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: {
        allowDuplicates: props.allowDuplicates || false,
        caseSensitive: props.caseSensitive || false,
        clearSelectionOnTyping: props.clearSelectionOnTyping || false,
        closeDropdownOnItemSelect: props.closeDropdownOnItemSelect || true,
        delimiter: props.delimiter || ",",
        freeInput: props.freeInput || true,
        highlightDuplicate: props.highlightDuplicate || true,
        highlightMatchesString: props.highlightMatchesString || true,
        itemValue: props.itemValue || undefined,
        itemText: props.itemText || undefined,
        maxTags: props.maxTags || undefined,
        maxChars: props.maxChars || undefined,
        minChars: props.minChars || 1,
        noResultsLabel: props.noResultsLabel || "No results found",
        placeholder: props.placeholder || "",
        removable: props.removable || true,
        searchMinChars: props.searchMinChars || 1,
        searchOn: props.searchOn || "text",
        selectable: props.selectable || true,
        source: props.source || undefined,
        tagClass: props.tagClass || "tag is-link",
        trim: props.trim || true,
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tagsInput = new BulmaTagsInput(
      this.refs.tagsInput,
      this.state.options
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { attribute, label, value, placeholder, changed } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">{label}</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            ref="tagsInput"
            type="text"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => changed(event)} // <--- this doesn't get called
            name={attribute}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your BulmaTagsInput you can bind event listeners to the instance.

eg.

```
inputTags.BulmaTagsInput().on('after.add', function(data) {
console.log(data.item);
    console.log(data.tag);
});
```

You can find more events in the docs: https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/tagsinput/1.0/get-started/javascript-api/